# C# dyanmic type and conditionals

Tags: c#

I have started using C# 4.0 and loving the dynamic keyword. However, I am not sure what I am doing can be considered as good practice. Please see the code below:

```
static void Main()
{
    NoobSauceObject noob = new NoobsauceObject();

    dynamic theReturnType = noob.do(param);

    if (theReturnType.GetType().ToString().Contains("TypeOne"))
        theReturnType.ExecuteMethodOfTypeOne();
    else if (theReturnType.GetType().ToString().Contains("TypeTwo"))
        theReturnType.ExecuteMethodOfTypeTwo();
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("");
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I found the above method quite easy and have been using it but not sure if it is something I should stick with in the long run.

EDIT: If I were to do the same using .NET 3.5 or lower, or without the dynamic keyword, what would be a good implementation?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Andrew: good point! I'm still learning C# so do forget some very important concepts sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like you're just doing a type-test between two unrelated types. If possible, I'd look at polymorphism here, or at least: implementing a common interface. However, the following would be fine too:

```
var typeOne = theReturnType as TypeOne;
if(typeOne != null) typeOne.ExecuteMethodOfTypeOne();
else {
    var typeTwo = theReturnType as TypeTwo;
    if(typeTwo != null) typeTwo.ExecuteMethodOfTypeTwo();
    else throw new ArgumentException("somethingMeaningful");
}
```

However, my preferred option is:

```
var typed = theReturnType as ISomeInterface;
if(typed != null) typed.SomeMethod();
else throw new ArgumentException("somethingMeaningful");
```

where `TypeOne` and `TypeTwo` might use explicit interface implementation to expose the method on their API:

```
public class TypeOne : ISomeInterface {
    void ISomeInterface.SomeMethod() { ExecuteMethodOfTypeOne(); }
    public void ExecuteMethodOfTypeOne() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(and likewise `TypeTwo`)

I can see no real use for `dynamic` here; For the return type of `noob.do(param)`, `object` would be fine in the first example - or `ISomeInterface` would be even better.

Comment: Marc: thank you for your feedback. I was using dynamic because the 'theReturnType' object could be of a type from 2 different classes. Good to learn something new everyday :)

Comment: @noobsauce interfaces can span unrelated classes - it is indeed part of the ***point*** of interfaces ;p

Comment: Marc: I implemented your technique. Its amazing. This was a wonderful lesson and I am glad I asked this question.